# Set up route to host on different ip range

Tags: networking, macos, routing

My Mac has local ip 172.16.1.2 and I would like to access (preferably using Safari or SSH) a host having ip 192.168.0.2 on the same network with submask 255.255.255.0. Is that possible?

I believe that I need to create a static route, but I can't really work out how to set that up.

```
.______.
|      |
|Router| 172.16.1.1
|______|
  |  |                .______.
  |  `----------------|      |
  |                   |Mac   | 172.16.1.2
  |        .______.   |______|
  `--------|      |   
           |NAS   | 
           |______| 192.168.0.2
```

Background: Got new router with ip range 192.168.0.0 instead of old 172.16.1.0. Changed my NAS to static ip 192.168.0.2, but forgot about firewall that only allows 172.16.1.0 (yes, stupid). Now, I can set the ip range on the router to 172.16.1.0, but I need to access the NAS on 192.168.0.2. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a diagram/map of your network?  I'm assuming you have two routers, with your OS X computer on one router, and everything else on the other, but seeing what connections they have in common would help.

Comment: as @ServiceManager asked for, we definitively need more information. what kind of NAS? you mention a firewall, but where is this firewall? BTW, if you can directly connect your computer with the NAS then you just have to set the computers IP to static in 192.168.0.0/24 network and you will be able to access your NAS.

Comment: Okay, let me just figure out the diagram/map thing. Both Mac and NAS are connected to the same router (an Apple Airport Extreme) which has the ip address 172.16.1.1. The NAS is a Synology Diskstation 209, which has a firewall that allows requests from the ip range 172.16.1.0. The Synology Assistant (program on my Mac) can find the NAS (with ip 192.168.0.2) when my Mac has ip 172.16.1.2, not if it has a 192.168.0.x address. But in that setup I cannot ping the NAS from terminal or access it via my browser.

Comment: @Zina. I should be able to connect the NAS directly to my Mac if that makes it any easier. However, I think I will still need my Mac to have a 172.16.1.x address in order for the firewall to allow access.

Comment: meaning you have a NAS with a 192 IP and the NAS firewall allows only access from a 172 IP? I would suggest a network settings reset described [here on the Synology site](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_reset_your_Synology_NAS)

Comment: @Zina Sounds like the perfect solution! I was so focused on networking me through this mess, I did not at all think in those terms. And I also did not know that you can reset only settings and not delete everything on the Synology. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your MAC to have a static IP address of 192.168.0.1, any netmask, no gateway nor DNS server needed. If you do not know how to do that, you may [read here](http://osxdaily.com/2010/12/17/set-static-ip-address-mac/).
2. Connect to your NAS via ssh, http, whichever you like.
3. When done, reboot the MAC.

**EDIT**:

The comment below, by @jreidal,

> Thank you, but I do not think it would have worked as the firewall rejected the ip range 192.168.0.0. I went with @Zina's suggestion and reset the network settings instead.

has made me realize how ill-understood my answer was. So I decided to expand a bit on it, should someone else with a simple problem like this wish to save him/herself the hassle of resetting the whole network.

Computers belonging to the same [network segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segment) do not need a router to talk to each other: they can just exchange packets by means of [MAC addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segment). So, why couldn't jreidal reach his NAS? Because the pc which he used to reach his NAS would check the NAS´IP address and, upon seeing that it does not belong to the LAN, would contact the router and tell it: please help me reach this NAS which is outside our LAN. The router would comply, but it would search the NAS on the outside of the LAN, thus missing its target.

If instead you assign to the pc an address within the same LAN as the NAS, the pc would realize that it does **not** need the mediation of the router, and would try to contact via ethernet frames the NAS **directly**, which it could easily do. This way the pc (a Mac) could change the NAS static IP address to a brand new address within the 172.16.1.0/24 network. Then all the Mac had to do was to go back to get an IP address served by its router (which can de done most easily by rebooting) and the problem would have been solved. I hope this layman explanation clears the reasoning behind my OP.

As for jreidal, as an old adage says, those who do not have a clear-thinking head should at least have good legs.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not think it would have worked as the firewall rejected the ip range 192.168.0.0. I went with @Zina's suggestion and reset the network settings instead.